# How to use Modal close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal like the one below.

I am using the below code to open the modal and I am trying to close the modal using the below code.

```js
$("#plan_templates").click(function() {
  $(".modal").modal("show");
  console.log("hello1");
});

$(".tplan").click(function() {
  var index = $(".tplan").index(this);
  $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.tab').eq(index).html());
});
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  console.log('hello2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="plan_templates">Add Plan Template</a>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        //more code here
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="tplan">
          //more code here
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="tplan">
          //more code here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this modal close is not working.

Comment: Put your jquery code inside $(document).ready(function(){ //your jquery code here });
It will work

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: @abu-abu Code seems to works perfect may be you have missed the placements where you have worked. Try to debug more. If you looking for any other question regarding please phrase your question as per required.